# santize data with zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, sanitization

im trying to write a function that will sanitize data coming from the client side.
im using zend framework and i know that it offers functions to do that. but im not using zend_form so i dont know how to use those functions

i wanna be able to sanitize the data from sql injections... before save them in the db or doing any further processing with that data.

so my question is , is there any function out there or a library that can do that ?
im looking for a function that will take as an input a string and return the sanitized one.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use prepared statements with PDO, Zend_Db or another ORM then the parameters will be escaped properly so that takes care of sanitizing in most cases.

PDO Example:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$pdo->execute(array($valueCol1, $valueCol2, $valueCol3));
```

Before you even get to that step though you should validate the data which is what [`Zend_Validate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html) is for. You dont have to use Zend_Validate with Zend_Form if you dont want to - you can just create validator instances and then validate different values.

Example from the ZF Documentation:

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();

if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
    // email appears to be valid
} else {
    // email is invalid; print the reasons
    foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $messageId => $message) {
        echo "Validation failure '$messageId': $message\n";
    }
}
```

Zend_Form is just a handy way to handle form processing and make things easily reusable.

Comment: well im not using PDO, all my models extend from zend_db_table. is that mean that i dont have to sanitize my data ? 

for the validation part. im validating all my data...

Comment: what about zend_db_table ? does it sanitize the data ?

Comment: It depends on how youre issuing your queries. If youre using the built in methods (like insert, delete, find, etc.) and what not and not going down to the adapater level, then yes its using prepared statements, which in turn are quoting the parameters. You should review the Zend_Db documentation more in depth and take a look at the code if necessary.